# Magento Code Debugging Through Eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse, debugging, magento, xdebug, magento-1.5

I am trying to debug Magento Code through Eclipse PDT. I configured X-Debugger properly and apply breakpoints in **index.php** file and launch the debugging session. I started debugging the code line by line but it get stop at last line of index.php file.

Actually i just want to debug the **one-page** checkout process of Magento. I have applied breakpoints in **OnepageController.php** file and gone through Onepage Checkout process but Eclipse does not stops at break points. Please help me.

Comment: Install one of the magento debug extensions and look which controller loading inthe session. Maybe, you are trying to wrong controller!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the debugger is working fine, i think the problem was occurring due to wrong configuration of eclipse PDT. To know how to configure eclipse PDT and X-debugger 
please visit
 
http://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/
http://subesh.com.np/2010/01/debugging-magento-eclipse-pdt-zend-debugger/

Comment: I found that Netbeans IDE is 100 times better the eclipse for php. All the things are already configured you just have to install and xdebug enable it form php.ini. Here is the download link [link](http://netbeans.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

I was busy for many days to find an installation (in 2012) for debugging Magento. Eclipse, Netbeans and PhpDeveloper all failed for XDebug (stopped only at first breakpoint) in a Xamp installation (my experience) and I could not load a ZendDebugger.dll as well. You find indeed a lot of outdated articles about this subject.

But finally I can debug Magento without problems (you need a debugger as a professional for Magento). I downloaded Zend Server CE and if you have a latest Eclipse PDT version downloaded (take the one from Zend) debugging works like a charm (all settings are done already by Zend, so no mistakes and wasting of time anymore). You should see when a webpage had finished that the php program had terminated (no error, is normal, for a next page php programs are started again). One problem yet Connect Manager does not install extensions anymore, BUT while debugging admin it works too (yes funny, but that’s Magento, it takes all your time). You can debug admin by adding /admin to the url in the debug browser window (just that simple).

Comment: Now the debugger is working fine, i think the problem was occurring due to wrong configuration of eclipse PDT.

Comment: The problem also is, in one environment it works and in another it don't. Difficult to find in that case what is going wrong (my experience). I tried also all the settings, some day it was working in Netbeans, but maybe because of Windows 7 not anymore. But with Zend Server (free to install) it is always working ..